# Load bundle based on what button pressed

Tags: java, android

I have two buttons in one class and those buttons send you to the same class but depending on what button that was pressed it will show different text/images/buttons.

So right now when a button is pressed it send you to the next class and adds some intets, like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
              public void onClick(View view) {  
                Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();  
                bundle1.putInt("top", R.drawable.1);  
                bundle1.putInt("mid", R.drawable.2);  
                bundle1.putInt("bot", R.drawable.3);  
                Intent intet1 = new Intent(curclass.this, nextclass.class);  
                intent1.putExtras(bundle1);  
                startActivity(intent1);
```

In the next class I have a bundle for each button but I belive I need to set a if/else on them to make sure it only uses one of the bundles because it does not work properly right now.

So how do I make the "if" thing?
I have tried but I don't know what to put after "if".
Something like

```
"if (button1 = pressed)  
(do this)  
else if (button2 = pressed)  
(do this)"
```

Thanks in advance!

Sorry if I explain like a idoit, might be because I am one and I just started to program.

EDIT: The problem is that I have two bundles in the second activity that looks like this:

```
Bundle asd = getIntent().getExtras();
    int asdasd = asd.getInt("top");
    im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagetop);
    im1.setImageResource(newimage);
    bu1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontop);
    bu1.setText("blahblah");
```

And I have the mid and bot one under that and then i have the second bundle which tells the Ints from button2 what images/texts to show and the problem is that it loads that second bundles stuff even if I press button1, which I suspect is caused by the bundles just being there side by side with anything telling them what to do.

I hope that clears it up :)

Comment: Only the bundle you passed into the Intent via setExtras will be visible in your second Activity. Can you elaborate on what exactly isn't working properly and perhaps post any relevant code from the second activity?

Comment: I edited OP with some more info :)

Comment: You say "The problem is that I have two bundles in the second activity that looks like this:" ... but I only see one bundle. Can you show the other bundle code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing of get... method of bundles it that you can define a default.

Put this wherever you want, maybe you have a class for constants, or where you better fill it to stay. Since it is static, you can access it wherever you want.
Create "global variables" the uniquely identify your buttons.

```
public static final int no_button = -1;
public static final int button_1 = 1;
public static final int button_2 = 2; //you are not forced to use -1, 1, 2, just use different numbers
```

Always in your first activity, after the button is pressed

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
              public void onClick(View view) {  
                Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle(); 
                bundle1.putInt("button id", button_1); 
                bundle1.putInt("top", R.drawable.1);  
                bundle1.putInt("mid", R.drawable.2);  
                bundle1.putInt("bot", R.drawable.3);  
                Intent intet1 = new Intent(curclass.this, nextclass.class);  
                intent1.putExtras(bundle1);  
                startActivity(intent1);
```

or

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
              public void onClick(View view) {  
                Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();  
                bundle2.putInt("button id", button_2);
                bundle2.putInt("top", R.drawable.1);  
                bundle2.putInt("mid", R.drawable.2);  
                bundle2.putInt("bot", R.drawable.3);  
                Intent intet2 = new Intent(curclass.this, nextclass.class);  
                intent2.putExtras(bundle1);  
                startActivity(intent1);
```

Then in the second activity

```
Bundle asd = getIntent().getExtras();
switch(asd.getInt("button id", -1)){
case button_1:
    [put here the code you want to execute if button1 was pressed]
case button_2:
     [put here the code you want to execute if button2 was pressed]
case no_button:
     [put here the code you want to execute if something else happened]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! However, this part I did not understand: "bundle.setInt("button id" the putton pressed id);" Where does that go and what does it mean?

Comment: @user1050429 i extended the answer. If you find it useful, please accept it

Comment: You are a god amongst men! This site is awesome!